# Mysql count with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have three tables:

**users:** id, name
**shifts:** id, date_start, date_end
**users_shifts:** user_id, shift_id

I want to get all the users who have done **n shifts** in a **specific date range**, where n can be any integer (also 0!).

I can get all the users with the number of shifts they have done like this:

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    COUNT(users_shifts.user_id) AS nr_shifts
FROM 
    users
LEFT JOIN 
    users_shifts ON users.id = users_shifts.user_id
GROUP BY 
    users.id
```

I have no clue how to:
1) add the date range to this query
2) limit the results to a specific nr_shifts

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still struggling? Provide a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
users.*,
COUNT(users_shifts.user_id) AS nr_shifts
FROM 
users
LEFT JOIN 
users_shifts ON users.id = users_shifts.user_id
WHERE shifts.date_end = '10/OCT/2012'
GROUP BY 
users.id
Order by users.id
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A second join doesn't do what you need?

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    COUNT(users_shifts.user_id) AS nr_shifts
FROM 
    users
LEFT JOIN 
    users_shifts ON users.id = users_shifts.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    shifts ON shifts.id = users_shifts.shift_id
WHERE
    shifts.date_start BETWEEN 2013-06-01 and 2013-06-30
    OR ISNULL(shifts.date_start)
GROUP BY 
    users.id
```

Comment: This works for the date range, but now I get only results where the user has at least one shift. I want only users with a specific number of shifts (which also can be 0).

Comment: apologies, left out the second half of the where clause.  It's in there now.